# USB 3.0 Device Power Failure

Tags: windows-8, usb

I have a 64 bit Windows 8 desktop that has 4 USB 3.0 ports. 
They have recently stopped working and I cannot figure out how to fix them. (My USB 2.0 ports work perfectly fine)

When I plug something in it will power it, but the computer will not recognize it.

Taking a look at the device manager, here is the problem it is having:

[image]

[image]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the driver and disabling and re-enabling it without success.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try this: http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2013/05/fix-usb-3-0-ports-issues-in-windows-8.html

Comment: Now I am having a problem with the "USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller". It says device cannot start (code 10)

Comment: Is still the same error shown?

Comment: Make sure there are no foreign objects stuck in any of the 3.0 ports. Check for 3.0 port damage also. Use a bright flashlight and magnifying glass if needed to visually inspect the ports.

Comment: Here are the errors I am getting now: http://imgur.com/a/gNRyx

Comment: The troubleshooter said that the device driver should be reinstalled. It tried and failed

Comment: OMG I ran Advanced SystemCare and it fixed it. If you want to post an answer I can accept it for your effort.